# Add custom tab with text from attribute

Tags: magento-1.9

I was added new atrribute with text, and want to see it like new tab, just after description. Was try many codes, but still nothing. Magento 1.9.1
Below my local.xml

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml">
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>description</alias>
        <title>More Information</title>
        <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
        <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>
    </action>

    <!-- sklad tab -->
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>sklad</alias>
        <title>Skład Produktu</title>
        <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
        <template>catalog/product/view/sklad.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <!-- end sklad -->

    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>upsell_products</alias>
        <title>We Also Recommend</title>
        <block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block>
        <template>catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>tabreviews</alias>
        <title>Reviews</title>
        <block>review/product_view_list</block>
        <template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag">
        <alias>tags</alias>
        <title>Tags</title>
        <block>tag/product_list</block>
        <template>tag/list.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>additional</alias>
        <title>Additional Information</title>
        <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
        <template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template>
    </action>

    <!-- Add custom tabs -->
    <block type="cms/block" name="block_product_tab1">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>block_product_tab1</block_id>
        </action>
    </block>
    <block type="cms/block" name="block_product_tab2">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>block_product_tab2</block_id>
        </action>
    </block>
</block>
<!-- end: Add tabs -->
```

And my sklad.phtml

```
<?php
$_prodID = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prodID );
echo $_product->getProduct_sklad();
?>
```

Can somebody help me? please.
B.R
Zydol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below link to create a custom tabs in your product details page

http://twincreations.co.uk/add-custom-product-tab-in-magento-1-9-ce/

And add the following code sizes.phtml:

```
  <?php
   $_product = $this->getProduct();
   $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('sizes_table');
   $attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
   foreach ($attributes as $attribute) 
   {
     if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
            if($attribute->getName() == 'sizes_table'){
                    echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
            }
     }
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: I thought that local.xml is the best solution, and are you sure that I need add static block?

Answer (score 0):

If your attribute name is `sklad`, code in `sklad.phtml`

```
<?php $_sklad = $this->getProduct()->getSklad(); ?>
<?php if ($_sklad): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('SKLAD') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_sklad, 'sklad') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: attribute name is "sklad"

Comment: @Zydol : I have updated my answer.

Comment: still the same, tab "Skład Produktu" is empty

Comment: Update to $_product->getProduct()->getSklad()

Comment: still empty :(((

Answer (score 0):

If your attribute name is sklad, code in sklad.phtml

```
 <?php
        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
        $_product = $this->getProduct();
        echo $_product->getData('sklad');

    ?>
```